# cx_freeze - how debug app

Tags: python, pyside, cx-freeze

I have small Python3 application for manipulating some specific XML files. For gui I am using PySide and for parsing files -lxml.

I had some troubles with freezing it with cx_freeze but finally succeed. Now - some parts of application simply don't work... no error message & no log created. 
For example on Enter press signal in LineEdit - new dialog should be shown... but nothing happens.

I have same version in standard python files and those are running correctly.  How do I debug the frozen application?

Comment: modules with magick must be included in feeze as full module.
`packages` derictive.

Comment: I don't think I get it... what Magick? And in packages I have lxml and my own modules just in case.

Comment: cxfreeze cant detect imports proceed with some technique like with getattr or eval etc. so try to list pyside and lxml in packages directive

Comment: how did you build a GUI .exe file with python 3+, cx_Freeze for windows ? I am fighting with cx_Freeze but did not succed: when I execute my .exe file nothing happens, no error message, no warning, no window opening, nothing... I already set base='Win32GUI' and the includes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way that worked for me is to implement some standard Python logging (see eg. [here](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook)). By regularly logging some DEBUG messages, you get an indication of where the problem occurs. If there are specific parts of the code that don't seem to work, wrap them in a try/except block and log the exception: The log will then give you the exact error message.

Comment: I think it's the only thing that can help me

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the pyside documentation and see if there is a redirect output to a window option - it is entirely possible that something is causing an error that is being printed out to nowhere.